# VB.net equivilent of Ruby's marshal - object save/load

Tags: vb.net

I'm just needing a simple bit of code for vb.net that will allow me to marshal an object into a string, allowing for the saving and loading of this string so I can save my classes, needs to be simple and easy!

Thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Serialization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730) to load and save objects to strings or binary data.